# Was the movie 3096 Days remade in English?

Tags: production, 3096-days

Was the movie [3096 Days](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1667355/) remade in English? Looks like the movie was a German movie. However, I saw this movie on TV in English. It didn't look like a dubbing as there were no obvious mismatches in the lip movements and the dialogues.

Answer (score 2):

Both [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1667355/) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3096) list the film as a German production with English language.

So it was not remade in English but already produced in English.

Found this in the [German Wikipedia entry](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/3096_Tage_(Film)):

> Um den Film auch international gut vermarkten zu können, wurde der Film mit international bekannten Schauspielern in englischer Sprache gedreht.

Rough translation by me:

> For better market success the film was produced with internationally known actors in English language.

Found [another source with a quote from the director Sherry Hormann](http://www.presseportal.de/pm/12946/2234717):

> "Nachdem wir im deutschsprachigen Raum auf viele Vorurteile, Befürchtungen und Ängste zu dem Stoff stießen, erlaubten wir uns über die sprachlichen Grenzen hinaus zu denken. Tatsächlich war es so, dass Antonia Campell-Hughes und Thure Lindhardt mit der unbeschwerten Außenansicht und der englischen Sprache einen für uns befreienden Blick auf die einzigartige Kraft der Geschichte erzeugten. [...]"

Rough translation by me:

> "After we met many prejudices, misgivings and fear to the source material in the German language area, we allowed ourselves to think over the language barrier."

Comment: would you know what the name of the film in the English language was? Did Antonia Campbell-Hughes star in it too? The one I saw had Antonia Campbell-Hughes in her skinny form.

Comment: The English title is only "3096" or sometimes "3096 Days". What do you mean with Campbell-Hughes starring also? There is only one movie.

Comment: Sorry if I sound confusing, did they shoot the scenes twice? One in English and one in German?

Comment: Ok now I understand your question, I think the movie was dubbed to German. But I can't find a source to confirm.